# How come the 'in' keyword isn't able to find an element in my array?

Tags: javascript, typescript

Below is returning the true

```
a = 'status'
a=='status'
```

while below is returning `false`

```
a = 'status'
a in ['status'] --> False
```

If `'=='` is returning `true` then please let me know why `'in'` is returning `false`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The `in` operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/in) doesn't check if an array/collection contains an element. It checks if the object on the right has a property with the name of the value on the left.

```
// Both return 'true'.
'foo' in { foo: 100, bar: 200 }
'filter' in ['hello']
```

You probably want to use [`indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf):

```
['status'].indexOf(a) >= 0
```

Or for newer versions of JavaScript, [`includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes):

```
['status'].includes(a)
```